# Injecting commands into JavaFX-hosted Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx

I have a [JavaFX Application](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108634/editing-javascript-and-rendering-html-in-one-window) I am building to help me build Javascript scripts. At its basic sense it has a raw text Pane on the left, and an HTML Pane on the right that shows a rendering of the entire HTML content provided through the left Pane. I was thinking how I can inject JavaScript statements into the HTML; and I was thinking I can put a WebSocket in the head or tail of the page that simply accepts lines of text passed to `exec`. Does that seem appropriate, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way.
You can call [executeScript](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-) to run javascript in your webview's [engine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html#getEngine--):

```
web.getEngine().executeScript( "document.body.textContent = 'FooBar' " );
```

The executeScript function will return result as JSObject, except for primitives and simple objects.
With this access you can get and set global variables like this:

```
JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
window.setMember( "foo", "bar" ); // Set window.foo to 'bar'
window.setMember( "console", new MyConsoleInJava() ); // You can also set Java objects!
```

> WebEngine also exposes some data in Java such as [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getDocument--) or [history](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getHistory--),
>   and they are more efficient in Java than in  JavaScript.

---

If you setup properties such as [onAlert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#onAlertProperty), you can even run interactive scripts:

```
webView.getEngine().setOnAlert( ( event ) -> {
   Alert alert = new Alert( AlertType.INFORMATION );
   alert.setTitle( "Webpage says" );
   alert.setContentText( event.getData() );
   alert.showAndWait();
});
webView.getEngine().executeScript( "alert('Mea')" );
```

Comment: Quick question. If I set a JavaScript object to a Java object, does the Java class need to be a specific type (does it need to implement or extend anything particular)?

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi No. I find that method overloading (including varargs) does not work as expected, but simple java methods using int, String, Array etc. will work perfect in js.  Other objects will be turned into JSObject.

Comment: Thanks. It is probably better to keep the interaction between the two simple, anyhow.